# NODE_DEBUG is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js

I'm very new to Node.js and currently facing a bump on the road. When i try using NODE_DEBUG to display a message. It says [NODE_DEBUG is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDF9r.jpg)

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, that command would not work. Instead, you should type

```
SET NODE_DEBUG=fulcrum&&node util.js
```